# Why is my docker build command failing to find npm?

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a simple dockerfile:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:11@sha256:a0abc98a9994ad188df7fd5755e078fe9b67b1f4c77ebdd9a51b0a16f2e4b9e3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
COPY package*.json ./
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

When I run it (docker build . -t patrick/id-mock) , the build rolls along quite happily until it gets to the 'RUN npm install' part and then it dies on me with the message:

```
[3/5] RUN npm install:
#5 0.217 /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
```

The whole of the output is as follows:

```
=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 243B                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 34B                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:11@sha256:a0abc98a9994ad188df7fd5755e078fe9b67b1f4c77ebdd9a51b0a16f2e4b9e3                                 2.1s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/eclipse-temurin:11@sha256:a0abc98a9994ad188df7fd5755e078fe9b67b1f4c77ebdd9a51b0a16f2e4b9e3                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring context: 18.53kB                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [2/5] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => ERROR [3/5] RUN npm install                                                                                                                                               0.2s
------
 > [3/5] RUN npm install:
#5 0.217 /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
```

Comment: `eclipse-temurin` is a Java image; Javascript is a different language.  Do you mean to build your image `FROM node:lts` instead?

Comment: changing the line to FROM node:lts gave me a similar problem but FROM node:16 seems to have done the trick.
Thanks.